# how to make random value in range a-z with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

i have python code which it will generate random value like

> JAY5uFy4F

this is the first output when i run python script
this is my code:

```
a= []
n=1
c=1
c2=3
Start= 10**(n-1)
End= (10**n)-1
while 1 :
    Num= random.randint(Start,End)
    Text= string.ascii_letters
    txt=''.join(random.choice(Text) for i in range(c))
    txt2=''.join(random.choice(Text) for i in range(c2))

    def Value():
        V= random.randint(3,6)
        vl= (f"JAY{V}{txt2}{Num}{txt}")
        return (vl)
    passwd =Value()
    if (passwd) not in (a):
        a.append (passwd)
        print(a)
    else:
        break
```

I know the code above will generate the sentence "JAY..." randomly
but what I want is to get [az][AZ] after the word "JAY..."

for example:

> JAY5abc1d
> JAY5bcd1e
> JAY5cde1f

etc
and also uppercase characters

> JAY5Abc1d
> JAY5Bcd1e
> JAY5Cde1f

until z, then when it reaches the last character the number changes

> JAY5Abc2d
> JAY5Bcd2e
> JAY5Cde2f

can anyone help me please

Comment: You can create single random characters [AZ] with `chr(random.randrange(65,89))` and [az] with `chr(random.randrange(97,122))`. Dont forget to write `import random` at the beginning. The range boundaries are according to the ASCII-Table adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Please don't re-ask the question on a different Stack Exchange site just because you don't get a prompt answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have a `while` loop in there...

You should just keep it simple. Write one function to generate a single password, like this:

```py
import random
import string

def generate_password(
    begin_sequence:str="JAY",
    input_characters:str=string.ascii_letters,
    random_numbers:tuple=(1,10),
    length_first_letters:int=3,
    length_second_letters:int=1,
    seed:float=None
) -> str:
    if seed is not None:
        random.seed(seed)
    check_val = random.randint(3,6)
    num = random.randint(random_numbers[0], random_numbers[1])
    txt1 = ''.join(random.choice(input_characters) for i in range(length_first_letters))
    txt2 = ''.join(random.choice(input_characters) for i in range(length_second_letters))
    return f"{begin_sequence}{check_val}{txt1}{num}{txt2}"
```

If you use the `seed` correctly, you'll get this result:

```py
>>> print(generate_password(begin_sequence="SYD", seed=10))
SYD3EKa7n
```

Then, just run a simple loop, calling this function each time:

```py
n = 1
Start = 10**(n-1)
End = (10**n)-1

for i in range(10):
    print(generate_password(begin_sequence="JAY", random_numbers=(Start,End)))
```

And you'll get a random password each time.